# What is better word.toUpperCase().chars() or word.chars().map(Chars::toUpperCase)?

Tags: java, string, java-stream

We need to get characters stream from string in upper case. There are two approaches:

1. `word.toUpperCase().chars()`
2. `word.chars().map(Character::toUpperCase)`

Which approach is better?

P.S. as requested in comments I specify the whole method where the code is used:

```java
private int[] toSortedChars(final String word) {
   return word.chars().map(Character::toLowerCase).sorted().toArray();
}
```

The method is used to solve the exercise:
https://exercism.org/tracks/java/exercises/anagram

Comment: My intuition told me that second approach is faster and better because it doesn't create an extra string.

Comment: The second approach has a larger footprint since it creates a stream and has simpler code. But have you tried to benchmark it at all?

Comment: It depends mostly on what you want to do with the resulting `IntStream`, could you maybe clarify that bit?

Comment: Note that we need to define "better". There are actually two aspects which may define "better": the *correctness* and the *performance*. [The answer by Hoopje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69070884/507738) focuses on correctness rather than performance.

Comment: I'm with Lino here - you need to tell us what you want to do with the capitalized characters. As Hoopje points out correctly, results will differ for some inputs. We cannot tell which version better matches your use case, and any performance consideration will depend on the terminal operation you have in mind for your stream.

Comment: @Lino I added the whole method where the code is used

Comment: So this has limitations anyway, beyond the issues mentioned in the answer. Unicode has characters spanning multiple `char` units and even multiple code points. If you accept the limitations of your approach, you could stay with the second approach, handling n:m case mappings wouldn’t result in understandable results after sorting anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first method is better.

The Javadoc of Character.toUpperCase mentions:

> In general, String.toUpperCase() should be used to map characters to uppercase. String case mapping methods have several benefits over Character case mapping methods. String case mapping methods can perform locale-sensitive mappings, context-sensitive mappings, and 1:M character mappings, whereas the Character case mapping methods cannot.

You may not be thinking about different languages than English right now, but at some point you might want to support other languages, and then capitalization becomes more difficult because characters cannot be capitalized on their own any more.

For example: `"Straße".toUpperCase()` returns `"STRASSE"` (even in English locales), which is behaviour that you cannot replicate if you are converting each character to upper case separately.

(Note: Recently, an uppercase "ß" was added to the German language, but it's not frequently used yet, except in capitalized names.)

Comment: This, of course, heavily depends on the subsequent operation(s). I wouldn’t be surprised if neither approach is recommended for whatever the OP actually wants to do…

Comment: Thank you for the very useful answer. I don’t know that one character may be mapped to severals.